# Oracle PL/SQL - how to use table of varchar in select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table type declared as

```
TYPE t_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(15) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

I am trying to use it in a procedure with a select statement, but it does not work:

```
procedure get_something (
    p_in_list  IN  t_table,
    p_out_list OUT t_table
)
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT item 
    BULK collect into p_out_list 
    from my_table 
    where myrow in (select * from table(p_in_list));
END get_something;
```

How can I use this in a select ... in statement?

Comment: Define "it does not work"

Comment: I get an "PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item" error when running the script.

Comment: what database version are you using ??

Comment: The ability to cast PL/SQL types into queryable tables has evolved over Oracle versions, with support for associative arrays only being added in 12.1. Even then, it makes a difference whether the type is declared in a package specification, package body or anonymous block etc.

Answer (score 2):

This it tested in 19.0. I don't have earlier versions to test on right now, but I think it will require at least 12.1.

First, if you need the type to be an associative array ('index by'), it needs to be in a package specification:

```
create or replace package demo_pkg
as
    type t_table is table of varchar2(15) index by pls_integer;
end demo_pkg;
```

Then SQL can see it:

```
declare
    -- type t_table is table of varchar2(15) index by pls_integer;
    subtype t_table is demo_pkg.t_table;

    from_list t_table;
    to_list   t_table;

    procedure get_something
        ( p_in_list  in  t_table
        , p_out_list out t_table )
    is
    begin
        select dummy bulk collect into p_out_list
        from   dual
        where  dummy in (select * from table(p_in_list));
    end get_something;
begin
    from_list(1) := 'X';
    from_list(2) := 'Y';
    from_list(3) := 'Z';

    get_something(from_list, to_list);
end;
```

From 18c you can populate the array declaratively using a qualified expression, e.g:

```
from_list t_table := demo_pkg.t_table(1 => 'X', 2 => 'Y', 3 => 'Z');
```

or

```
get_something
( demo_pkg.t_table(1 => 'X', 2 => 'Y', 3 => 'Z')
, to_list );
```

Some of these restrictions are because associative arrays aren't really a natural fit for SQL queries, and support for them took a while to be added. If you declare `t_table` as a regular nested table, it should work in an earlier version:

```
create or replace package demo_pkg
as
    type t_table is table of varchar2(15);
end demo_pkg;
```

or create it as a standalone SQL object:

```
create or replace type t_table as table of varchar2(15);
```

This also makes a `member of` construction possible:

```
declare
    from_list t_table := t_table('X','Y','Z');
    to_list   t_table;

    procedure get_something
        ( p_in_list  in  t_table
        , p_out_list out t_table )
    is
    begin
        select dummy bulk collect into p_out_list
        from   dual
        where  dummy member of p_in_list;
    end get_something;
begin
    get_something(from_list, to_list);
end;
```

`member of` only works with "nested table" collections, not associative arrays or varrays. I can never really see the point of varrays, unless the  size limit is so useful for your business logic that you can live with all the lost functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option; see if it helps.

Sample table and type:

```
SQL> create table my_table as
  2    select dname item, loc myrow from dept;

Table created.

SQL> create or replace type t_table as varray(20) of varchar2(20);
  2  /

Type created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure
  2    get_something (
  3      p_in_list  in  t_table,
  4      p_out_list out t_table
  5    )
  6    is
  7    begin
  8      select item
  9      bulk collect into p_out_list
 10      from my_table
 11      where myrow in (select * from table(p_in_list));
 12    end get_something;
 13  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_in  t_table;
  3    l_out t_table;
  4  begin
  5    l_in := t_table();
  6    l_in.extend(2);
  7    l_in(1) := 'DALLAS';
  8    l_in(2) := 'NEW YORK';
  9
 10    get_something(l_in, l_out);
 11
 12    for i in 1 .. l_out.count loop
 13      dbms_output.put_line(l_out(i));
 14    end loop;
 15  end;
 16  /
RESEARCH
ACCOUNTING

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```