# Populating a temporary table and using the data for updating and inserting

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following code:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE table_invoice IS RECORD
                           (
                               invoiceId  number(15),
                               status     number(10),
                           );
    TYPE invoice_data_table IS TABLE OF table_invoice;
    invoice_data invoice_data_table;
BEGIN

select inv."InvoiceId",
       inv."Status",
           bulk collect
    into invoice_data
    from "Invoice" inv join "Company" c on inv."CompanyId" = c."Id"
    where c."CompanyType" = 1
```

Here i store the select data to be used later on for updating and inserting.
Unfortunately, bulk update doesn't work.

```
Update "Invoice"
set "Status"                 = 200,
    "LastModifiedDate"       = (select sysdate from dual)
where "InvoiceId" in (select invoiceId from invoice_data); -- this select doesn't work, so the entire update will fail, why?

FOR i IN 1 .. invoice_data.count 
LOOP
    insert into "InvoiceStatusChange" ("Date", "NewStatus", "InvoiceId", "CompanyId")
    select inv."InvoiceDate", inv."Status", inv."InvoiceId", inv."CompanyId" from "Invoice"
    inv where "InvoiceId" = invoice_data(i).InvoiceId;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Now the update doesn't work. It only works if I move to the *for* loop and update the record one-by-one, same as I do for inserting.
Is there a way to do this in one go? Similarly how I'm trying to update the invoices, do an insert into the *"Invoice"* table from a select statement by using properties from the "*Invoice*" table by passing ids from the cached `invoice_data`?
Something like this:

```
insert into "InvoiceStatusChange" ("Date", "NewStatus", "InvoiceId", "CompanyId")
select inv."InvoiceDate", inv."Status", inv."InvoiceId", inv."CompanyId" from "Invoice"
inv where "InvoiceId" in (select invoiceId from invoice_data);
```

so basically, use a `insert into select` syntax by passing a list of Ids, rather than going one-by-one?

Comment: Have you read the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63644770/oracle-pl-sql-how-to-use-table-of-varchar-in-select-statement ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `update`, try `merge`. Here's an example based on Scott's schema; I'm not doing anything *smart* here, it is just to illustrate how to do it.

Create types at SQL level:

```
SQL> create or replace type table_invoice is object (empno number, job varchar2(20));
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type invoice_data_table is table of table_invoice;
  2  /

Type created.
```

This is initial table contents; I'll update `JOB` column's value:

```
SQL> select * from emp where deptno = 20;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        840                    20
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.81       2975                    20
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09.12.82       3000                    20
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12.01.83       1100                    20
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.81       3000                    20
```

Here's the procedure; check the `using` clause (lines #10 and 11):

```
SQL> declare
  2    invoice_data invoice_data_table;
  3  begin
  4    select table_invoice(e.empno, e.job)
  5      bulk collect into invoice_data
  6      from emp e
  7      where e.deptno = 20;
  8
  9    merge into emp a
 10      using (select empno, job
 11             from table(cast(invoice_data as invoice_data_table))
 12            ) x
 13      on (a.empno = x.empno)
 14      when matched then update set
 15        a.job = 'x' || x.job;
 16  end;
 17  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From emp where deptno = 20;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      xCLERK          7902 17.12.80        840                    20
      7566 JONES      xMANAGER        7839 02.04.81       2975                    20
      7788 SCOTT      xANALYST        7566 09.12.82       3000                    20
      7876 ADAMS      xCLERK          7788 12.01.83       1100                    20
      7902 FORD       xANALYST        7566 03.12.81       3000                    20

SQL>
```

Comment: Nice, though you don't need an explicit cast after about Oracle 9i :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`FORALL` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/FORALL-statement.html#GUID-C45B8241-F9DF-4C93-8577-C840A25963DB) for batched DML from PL/SQL. It doesn't require new schema-level objects. And it's not a handy shortcut for `loop`: it is pure batched binding.

Setup:

```
create table main_table
as
select
  level as id,
  'status' || mod(level, 3) as status,
  trunc(level/5) as ref_id,
  lpad(level, 4, '0') as some_data
from dual
connect by level < 25
/

create table ref_tab
as
select
  level as id,
  mod(level, 2) as type_
from dual
connect by level < 4
/

create table main_table_status (
  dt date default sysdate,
  id int,
  old_ varchar2(20),
  new_ varchar2(20)
)
```

(Bulk) collect IDs and before values that will be updated, then perform `forall` for update and for insert:

```
declare
  type tr_main_table is record (
    id main_table.id%type,
    status main_table.status%type
  );
  type tt_main_table is table of tr_main_table;
  lt_main_table tt_main_table;
  c_status constant varchar2(5) := 'upd';
begin
  /*id to update*/
  select
    id, status

    bulk collect into lt_main_table
  from main_table m
  where m.ref_id in (
    select flt.id
    from ref_tab flt
    where flt.type_ = 1
  );

  dbms_output.put_line(lt_main_table.count());

  /*update*/
  forall i in lt_main_table.first..lt_main_table.last
    update main_table
    set status = c_status
    where id = lt_main_table(i).id;

  /*log status*/
  forall i in lt_main_table.first..lt_main_table.last
    insert into main_table_status(id, old_, new_)
    values(
      lt_main_table(i).id,
      lt_main_table(i).status,
      c_status
    );
end;/
```

```
1 rows affected

dbms_output:
10
```

That results in:

```
select *
from main_table_status
order by id
```

| DT | ID | OLD_ | NEW_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 5 | status2 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 6 | status0 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 7 | status1 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 8 | status2 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 9 | status0 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 15 | status0 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 16 | status1 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 17 | status2 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 18 | status0 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 19 | status1 | upd |

```
select *
from main_table
where status = 'upd'
order by 1
```

| ID | STATUS | REF_ID | SOME_DATA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | upd | 1 | 0005 |
| 6 | upd | 1 | 0006 |
| 7 | upd | 1 | 0007 |
| 8 | upd | 1 | 0008 |
| 9 | upd | 1 | 0009 |
| 15 | upd | 3 | 0015 |
| 16 | upd | 3 | 0016 |
| 17 | upd | 3 | 0017 |
| 18 | upd | 3 | 0018 |
| 19 | upd | 3 | 0019 |

But you may optimize an access. Since you use additional table just for filtering, it worth to do it explicitly via subquery in `where`: either `in` or `exists`. Join is meant to add new information, and filtering is somewhat a side effect of it: you obviously do not want to care about key columns and deal with duplicated rows which may be produced by join when the only requirement is to filter.

Thus, moving filtering into `where` you may directly use it in `update` statement that has `returning` clause and you may `bulk collect` this also. It will save one  additional access to the same table: retrieve the values from `update` rather than preliminary `select`.

Then do the same `forall` insert into your additional table.

```
declare
  type tr_main_table is record (
    id main_table.id%type,
    status main_table.status%type
  );
  type tt_main_table is table of tr_main_table;
  lt_main_table tt_main_table;
  c_status constant varchar2(5) := 'upd_2';
begin
  dbms_session.sleep(2);

  /*update*/
  update (
    /*subquery to generate a column
    with before value*/
    select
      m.*,
      /*scalar subquery to unlink the value
      from the original column name*/
      (select m.status from dual) as old_status
    from main_table m
    where m.ref_id in (
      select flt.id
      from ref_tab flt
      where flt.type_ = 1
    )
  )
  set status = c_status
  returning id, old_status

    bulk collect into lt_main_table
  ;

  dbms_output.put_line(lt_main_table.count());

  /*log status*/
  forall i in lt_main_table.first..lt_main_table.last
    insert into main_table_status(id, old_, new_)
    values(
      lt_main_table(i).id,
      lt_main_table(i).status,
      c_status
    );
end;/
```

```
1 rows affected

dbms_output:
10
```

Which results in this content of logging table:

```
select *
from main_table_status
order by dt, id
```

| DT | ID | OLD_ | NEW_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 5 | status2 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 6 | status0 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 7 | status1 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 8 | status2 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 9 | status0 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 15 | status0 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 16 | status1 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 17 | status2 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 18 | status0 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:15 | 19 | status1 | upd |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:17 | 5 | upd | upd_2 |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:17 | 6 | upd | upd_2 |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:17 | 7 | upd | upd_2 |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:17 | 8 | upd | upd_2 |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:17 | 9 | upd | upd_2 |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:17 | 15 | upd | upd_2 |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:17 | 16 | upd | upd_2 |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:17 | 17 | upd | upd_2 |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:17 | 18 | upd | upd_2 |
| 2023-05-20 00:47:17 | 19 | upd | upd_2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iJmf4B7R)